# What does "1" says in group aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the following example (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#_S_group) there is a source sample:

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$author",
        docsPerAuthor : { $sum : 1 }, // here goes the question
        viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }
    }}
);
```

My question is: what **`1`** is actually referring to (which field)? What can be written instead? Can it be `$author` for example?

And, in general - how am I supposed to *"read"* this: `viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }` - is it *"viewsPerAuthor is a sum of pageViews"*?

Comment: It means $inc by one or start at one if field is not set.

Comment: If so, what `$pageViews` means in the next line? This is confusing.

Comment: It means sum up the total for that field called `pageViews`, so you can either sum up a field or you can just count how many times that field is aggregated across a group, or in SQL `SELECT COUNT(*) as docsPerAuthor, SUM(pageViews) AS viewsPerAuthor FROM article GROUP BY author`

Comment: I think it would be best to list this thread as an answer - I'll approve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through this bit by bit:

```
docsPerAuthor : { $sum : 1 },
```

Means that for every document in this group (per author) make a new field called `docsPerAuthor` and either `$inc` it by `1` or make its initial field value `1`.

```
viewsPerAuthor : { $sum : "$pageViews" }
```

Means that for every document in this group sum up the `pageViews` field of the documents that match this particular group.

It is basically the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as docsPerAuthor, SUM(pageViews) AS viewsPerAuthor 
       FROM article GROUP BY author
```